# Short form for "collige, virgo, rosas"

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax

I've never studied Latin, so probably I'm asking a trivial question.
I'm wondering if the phrase

*"collige, virgo, rosas"*

can be expressed correctly in the following short form

*"collige rosas"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. *Collige, virgo, rosas* means "gather roses, maiden", *collige rosas* means "gather roses".

*Collige* is the active 2nd person singular present imperative of *colligo* 'to gather'.

*Rosas* is the accusative plural of *rosa* 'rose'; accusative because it's the direct object of *collige*.

*Virgo* is the vocative singular of *virgo* 'maiden'; vocative because the maiden is being addressed by the speaker.